# Implementing a boolean table like structure in MFC

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc, associative-array, relation

I want to implement a structure, almost like boolean table, in my MFC application. the row index and column index will be a list of strings and will be same on both axes. Also I don't know the size initially. Example:

```
Table[string1][string1]=0
Table[string1][string2]=0
Table[string1][string3]=1
Table[string1][string4]=1
Table[string2][string1]=1
Table[string2][string2]=0
Table[string2][string3]=0
Table[string2][string4]=1
```

and so on...

What is the best way to implement this kind of structure in MFC? 2D vector? If so then how?

Comment: I guess 2D `vector` is more "c++" than 2D `array`

Comment: What do you mean by "how" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Least effort:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, bool>> relation;

int main()
{
  relation r;
  r["string1"]["string1"] = false;
  r["string1"]["string2"] = true;

  std::cout << r["string1"]["string1"] << " "
            << r["string1"]["string2"] << " "
            << r["string1"]["string3"] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Please consider that the default value for an uninitialized couple of strings is `false` (e.g. `r["string1"]["string3"] == false`).

A similar idea would be to use an ordinary linear map in which the key is a `std::pair` of strings. It's probably faster but with a slightly different syntax.

Depending on your requirements a map/nested map data structure could be space inefficient or too slow.